# View() method abruptly started returning Blank HTML

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, laravel-5

I am facing an issue where my views abruptly stopped rendering on the Server. Only a blank white page is displayed with no errors logged. Returning a String works fine on Server. I deployed the project on my local machine and everything works fine (Local Machine has Apache).

View Inspect :

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

Permissions :

```
drwxr-xr-x 10 nobody nobody 4.0K Nov 26 20:07 app
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody nobody 1.7K Nov 26 20:07 artisan
drwxr-xr-x  3 nobody nobody 4.0K Nov 26 20:07 bootstrap
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody nobody 1.5K Nov 26 20:07 composer.json
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody nobody 133K Nov 27 09:56 composer.lock
-rwxr-xr-x  1 nobody nobody 1.8M Nov 26 20:08 composer.phar
drwxr-xr-x  2 nobody nobody 4.0K Nov 26 20:07 config
drwxr-xr-x  5 nobody nobody 4.0K Nov 26 20:07 database
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody nobody  503 Nov 26 20:07 gulpfile.js
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody nobody  159 Nov 26 20:07 package.json
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody nobody  228 Nov 27 01:07 php_errors.log
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody nobody 1.1K Nov 26 20:07 phpunit.xml
drwxr-xr-x  6 nobody nobody 4.0K Nov 26 20:07 public
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody nobody 1.9K Nov 26 20:07 readme.md
drwxr-xr-x  5 nobody nobody 4.0K Nov 26 20:07 resources
-rw-r--r--  1 nobody nobody  567 Nov 26 20:07 server.php
drwxrwxrwx  6 nobody nobody 4.0K Nov 26 20:07 storage
drwxr-xr-x  2 nobody nobody 4.0K Nov 26 20:07 tests
drwxr-xr-x 34 nobody nobody 4.0K Nov 27 09:56 vendor
```

Controller :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;


class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function test(){
        Log::info("Reached Test Controller");
        return view("test");
    }

}
```

View (test.blade.php) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sample View</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>We Are heere</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Nginx Conf :

```
    location @optimusrewrite {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /optimus/public/index.php?_url=/$1;
}

location /optimus/public/
{
    try_files $uri $uri/ @optimusrewrite;
    index index.php;
}
```

** Update **

Removing the `.blade` extension from `test.blade.php` renders the view.

Comment: Check error logs. If it is production server, it will have `display_errors` disabled, which will cause a "white screen of death" on error.

Comment: I have debug enabled (`APP_DEBUG=true`) and I'm not seeing any errors on `laravel.log`

Comment: Hi Raul. Can you try changing ownership of files to nginx user like this sudo chown -R nginx:nginx

Comment: Hi Silvanus, I have other projects running on the same server with identical ownership and they are working fine except the above mentioned Project.

Comment: Removing the `.blade` extension renders the blade correctly. For instance; 
`test.blade.php` -> `test.php` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was resolved by chmod'ing the resource directory (`chmod -R 775 resource/`)

Answer (score 1):

Hi I had the same issue once

run `php artisan view:clear` in console.. or delete the compiled view files from `storage/framework/views`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Adnan, still no change.